# Can I configure Google Global Load Balancer for multi region GKE Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, istio, google-anthos

I have two GKE clusters running in two different regions. Anthos Service Mesh is configured in each region for inter API communication. Question is should I configure Google Global Load Balancer to send the traffic or should I configure Istio Ingress gateway/Anthos Ingress gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, According to the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features?hl=en#backends) you can configure External HTTP(S) LB for Multi-region cluster. For more information please follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features?hl=en).